# Сортировка сгенерированного массива по убыванию

Tags: c++builder, массивы, c++

C++ Builder 6

Программа генерирует массив и надо, чтобы она отсортировала его по убыванию... Но у меня выдает ошибку...

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
 Memo1->Lines->Clear();
   const int size = 25;
   int *array = new int[size];
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      array[i] = random(100);
      Memo1->Lines->Add(array[i]);
     }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
   Form1->Memo5->Lines->SaveToFile("prom");
TStringList *r;
r->LoadFromFile("prom"); //vot zdes' oshybka
//r->Add(Form1->Memo5->Lines->Strings[2]); i tak toje
Form1->Memo5->Lines->Clear();
r->Sort();
Form1->Memo5->Lines->AddStrings(r);
}
```

Comment: У Вас сгенерированный массив записывается в компонент Memo1, а считывать вы пытаетесь из компонента Memo5. Возможно в этом ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

```
TStringList *r = new TStringList;
.........
delete r;
```

В первом обработчике тоже надо бы delete[]array;
Еще не плохо было бы написать какая ошибка.

Comment: спасибо....помогло!!